# When working with trochoids what does θ stand for?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, curves

These are the formulas with which you can draw trochoids.

$x = aθ - b sin(θ)$

$y = a - b cos(θ)$

I'm trying to make trochoids but I got hung up on this symbol $θ$, what is it and how do I use it, I understand what $a$ and $b$ stand for in there formulas but I'm having a hard time finding out what I should fill in for $θ$.

Comment: $\theta$ is the rotation angle.

Comment: You give it different values and that gives you corresponding values of $x$ and $y$.  Small gaps (e.g. $\pi / 100$ will give you a smoother curve.

Comment: It is simply a real parameter, denoted by the Greek letter theta. You can replace it with $t$.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ is the variable for function $f(x)$, $θ$ is the variable of your parametric function.